# Java Applet doesn't find included JAR files on Windows

Tags: java, windows, applet, windowserror

I'm using JTDS driver to connect to a SQL Server... I included the JAR file into the proyect... I compiled the proyect into a jar file, I signed the jar file. I uploaded it to a my website.

When I test it on Ubuntu works like a charm.
but on Windows shows an error "No suitable driver found" (or something like that). It seems that windows dosen't find the JTDS Driver JAR file... because if I extract the jar file into my website directory the error dissapears, but it shows me some permissions errors because there is no signed jar...

What can I do?

Comment: Which version of JTDS are you using? I had some similar problems with 1.3.* and R. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14513224/connecting-to-ms-sql-server-from-r-on-mac-linux/18154453#18154453

Comment: The lastone... 1.3.1
Let's see...

Comment: I solved it, just added ,jtds-1.3.1.jar to de ARCHIVE propety in the applet html etiquette.