# Authentication with MS SQL Server from Mac OS X

Tags: java, sql-server, r

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14513224/connecting-to-ms-sql-server-from-r-on-mac-linux) I've built the following function, which seems to connect to the SQL Server but is unable to authenticate:

```
  connect <- function(server, database, user, password){
  # Autoinstall if necessary
  packages <- c("RJDBC")
  new.packages <- packages[!(packages %in% installed.packages()[, "Package"])]
  if(length(new.packages)){
    install.packages(new.packages, dependencies = TRUE)
  }

  library(RJDBC)
  sql.java <- paste(find.package(package = 'mypackage'), '/sqljdbc4.jar', sep = "")
  drv <- JDBC("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver", 
    sql.java, 
    identifier.quote = "`")

  con.string <- paste("jdbc:sqlserver://", server, ";databaseName=", database, ";integratedSecurity=true;", sep = "")
  con <- dbConnect(drv, con.string, user, password)
  }

#  Feb 24, 2015 9:57:56 AM com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.AuthenticationJNI <clinit>
#  WARNING: Failed to load the sqljdbc_auth.dll cause : no sqljdbc_auth in java.library.path
#  Show Traceback

#  Rerun with Debug
#  Error in .jcall(drv@jdrv, "Ljava/sql/Connection;", "connect", as.character(url)[1],  : 
#   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: This driver is not configured for integrated authentication. ClientConnectionId:5ac4ed9c-a4a8-4318-ba77-7f3fb2ed01b0 

# If I take ;integratedSecurity=true out of there:

# Error in .jcall(drv@jdrv, "Ljava/sql/Connection;", "connect", as.character(url)[1],  : 
#   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user 'domain\user'. ClientConnectionId:29035eb6-7b9f-4d9c-86b4-6d6760c61399
```

Does anyone know how I can handle authentication? It seems to work with RODBC on my Windows machine.

Comment: You are using integrated security, which means your Mac must have a Windows login. Try dropping it from the connection string.

Comment: `Error in .jcall(drv@jdrv, "Ljava/sql/Connection;", "connect", as.character(url)[1],  : 
   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user 'domain\user'. ClientConnectionId:29035eb6-7b9f-4d9c-86b4-6d6760c61399`

Comment: any progress? I am having the same problem. My SQL server requires windows authentication and I am connection from a Windows client.